# Where to host my MVC4 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm looking for a hosting company that would support MVC4 but I couldn't find any different from Windows Azure - I would like to deploy my MVC4 application online but I do not know a hosting company with good prices. Could you mention me a list?

Comment: Found this gem that is provided by microsoft. Full list of providers + comments from users. http://www.microsoft.com/web/hosting/home

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many out there I'm sure that when you Google the words "mvc 4 hosting", will show up. But here are a couple that I've tried in the past and were reliable when I hosted my sites with them:

- [Discount ASP](http://discountasp.net/sp_mvc-hosting.aspx) - shared hosting
- [Winhost](http://www.winhost.com/windows-hosting-plans.aspx) - shared hosting

If you are looking for a cloud-based, Azure-like hosting then you might want to check out the following:

- [Amazon for .Net](http://aws.amazon.com/net/)
- [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/) - built on top of Amazon

Also, if you are going for shared hosting it is important that you host with those that allow Full Trust to your site. Many have met problems with their host providers when their sites are not granted Full Trust and resulted to either an erratic site or not running at all.

Comment: do you know if GoDaddy support this feature?

Comment: I'm not sure, have you gone to their site or asked their support? I don't think GoDaddy specializes on .net hosting. I use them as a registrar only. I suggest you go with those companies who have worked with .net applications, meaning that .net sites were deployed to their servers for a number of thousands.

Comment: @DarfZon, you have a pretty good answer to a question people want to close. time to appreciate and move on

Comment: This company given good service to me http://www.smarterasp.net/

Comment: Please do not use  http://www.smarterasp.net if you want to store large number of files. All of their plan said that there is unlimited space, but actually you will get 5GB for basic and 10GB for advanced